# android how to create a notification that never closes

Tags: android

I have created notification using NotificationCompat.builder. But i cant set flags through it to make uncancelable.

Can anyone please help me to solve my problem, i would be grateful to you. :)

Thank you :)

```
noti_intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    noti_pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, noti_id, noti_intent, 0);
    noti_manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_ico)
    .setContentTitle("Next alarm is set to ring on")
    .setTicker("Alarm is set to ring")
    .setContentText(next_date.getText()+" "+next_time.getText())
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(noti_pend)
    .setAutoCancel(false);
```

Answer (score 10):

Replace `setAutoCancel(true)` with `setOngoing(true)`.

Comment: @commonsware, i use setOngoing(true) my app shows a notification with progressbar and a content title, does some work and removes the progressbar and changes the content title and sets setOngoing(false). this works perfectly for jellybean but on android 2.3.3 i dont get notification for the first part that is the progressbar and title, after doing its work it directly shows the 2nd part of my notification i.e without progress bar and changed content... 

is this could be because of using **setOngoing(true)**..?

Answer (score 4):

Try including the `.setOngoing(true)` in your code:

```
noti_intent = new Intent(this, Main.class);
    noti_pend = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, noti_id, noti_intent, 0);
    noti_manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.status_ico)
    .setContentTitle("Next alarm is set to ring on")
    .setTicker("Alarm is set to ring")
    .setContentText(next_date.getText()+" "+next_time.getText())
    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
    .setContentIntent(noti_pend)
    .setOngoing(true)    
    .setAutoCancel(false);
```